# vbscript - displaying a message box when an OnClick event fires

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I feel a bit silly asking this question, since most of the questions people ask on here are way beyond my level as a programmer, but at least I know I'm in good hands as far as asking goes. I used to know how to make simple vbscript and javascript programs, but I'm a bit rusty. I'm trying to refresh myself, and despite repeated google/other searches, can't recall how to make it so that when a button is clicked, a msgbox appears. Also, I'd like to know how to modify the .value attribute of a textbox. I'm attempting this in vbscript for now, but I'll try javascript if anyone knows a way to do it in that instead. My ultimate goal is a text based type game where you can click buttons labeled, "north,south,west,east", and make it like an rpg. The textbox would display the current room description.

Here's the code I have so far, which isn't displaying the msgbox.

```
    <html>
    <title>Explor-o-Rama!</title>

    <body>
    <form name = frmMain>


    <textarea name = "txtDisp" rows = "10" cols = "50"></textarea><br>
    <input type = "button" name = cmdTest value = "test">
    </form>

   <script language = "vbscript">

    sub cmdTest_OnClick

    msgbox "test"


    end sub

    <script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You omit this the closed tag </script> and it works of course in HTA or with IE only not with other browsers

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```html
msgbox "test"
```

The correct command is:

```html
MsgBox("test")
```

OR

```html
X=MsgBox("test")
```

This SHOULD DO IT.

Answer (score -1):

also, `<html><body><script language=vbscript>msgbox "" </script></body></html>` not works.

but this code works OK:

```
<html><body><script>alert('Test');</script></body></html>

<html>
<body>
<script>
    function test()
    {
        alert('Test');
    }
</script>
<input type = 'button';  onclick='test()'>
</body>
</html>
```

Probably, it's a IE internal bug.